# Trying to understand .apply() in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to avoid looping through dataframes so started using .apply() recently.

However I don't really understand the behaviour. I have a super easy toy example below. The user is asked if each fruit in the column is an apple (they're all apples so every answer is Y).

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.DataFrame({'fruit':['apple','apple', 'apple','apple', 'apple'],'result':['']*5})
df

   fruit result
0  apple       
1  apple       
2  apple       
3  apple       
4  apple
```

Set up an `.apply()` function to ask the user if the fruit is an apple:

```
def check_fruit(row):

    # get the current fruit in the row
    current_fruit = row['fruit']

    # print output for user
    print('\n===============================================')
    print('Is this an apple?')
    print('===============================================\n')
    print(f'Current Fruit: {current_fruit}\n')

    # user input - they are asked if the displayed fruit
    # is an apple or not and must enter y/n
    choice = input('Please enter Y/N: ')

     # if they choose yes
    if (choice == 'Y' or choice == 'y'):

        # add the word 'correct' to row column
        row['result']=='Correct'

        return row
    # if they choose no
    elif (choice == 'N' or choice == 'n'):

        # add the word 'Incorrect' to row column
        row['result']=='Incorrect'

        return row
```

Now apply it - notice the output. Why is apple printed 6 times when there are only 5 rows in the dataframe?

```
df= df.apply(check_fruit,axis=1)

===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y


===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y


===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y


===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y


===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y


===============================================
Is this an apple?
===============================================

Current Fruit: apple

Please enter Y/N: y
```

Secondly, why isn't the row being returned from the apply function? The 'result' column is still empty after the function has been applied.

```
   fruit result
0  apple       
1  apple       
2  apple       
3  apple       
4  apple
```

It's probably something painfully obvious I know...

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

(ps. i know there is no error checking with the input, just focusing on .apply() now)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the documentation for [`pd.DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> **Notes**
>
> ---
>
> In the current implementation apply calls *func* twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if *func* has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.

Your function `check_fruit` does have side-effects, namely asking the user for some input, which happens once more than you would expect.

In general, `apply` and other data frame functions are meant to be used with functions that transform the data in some way, not with application logic. You do not get any particular benefit for not writing out the loop explicitly in this case, so the best you can do is probably just go through each row by hand:

```
import pandas as pd

def check_fruit(row):
    # ...

df = pd.DataFrame({'fruit': ['apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'],
                   'result': [''] * 5})
for row in df.iterrows():
    check_fruit(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

@jdehesa explained why the first row was being repeated.

My second question was: why isn't the new data being returned. I found the problem, very noob mistake. I had `row['result']=='Correct'` instead of `row['result']='Correct'` .i.e. `==` vs `=`.